# How to modify value in form 3 from form 2 in c sharp windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a simple ATM which consist of 3 forms.
`Form 1` contains 3 buttons: Balance and Withdrawal.
`Form 2` is the balance form, shown when the user click the balance button. It shows the current balance, which is set to 5000 as a default value and it is displayed in a text box.
`Form 3` is the withdrawal form, shown when the user clicks the withdrawal button. It contains a text box for the amount that the user wants to withdraw and an Okay button.

My question is how am I going to change the value of balance when the user withdraws an amount?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use an AtmModel class to store your balance.

```
public class AtmModel
{
    public int Balance { get; set; }

    public void WithdrawBalance (int amount)
    {
        this.Balance -= amount;
    }
}
```

Your main form should have a private field which stores your AtmModel. This model is initialized in your View's (Form) constructor.

Each of your additional forms opened from the main form should have a constructor with an AtmModel parameter.

Now you can pass your model to your other forms, you are able to access the Balance property and the WithdrawBalance methods.

So basicly like this:

```
public partial class AtmMainView : Form
{
   AtmModel model;

   public AtmMainView()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      this.model = new AtmModel();
   }

   private void Withdraw_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
   {
      AtmWithdrawView form = new AtmWithdrawView(this.model);
      form.Show();
   }
}
```

So when you click your Withdraw button on your main form, you open your other form with the referenced *AtmModel*. On your *WithdrawForm* you can now apply a click event on the *OK* button, to execute *AtmModel.WithdrawBalance*, with the amount declared in your textbox.

This design is however far from perfect, but it offers you a way to solve your problem.

For more information please read:
[Getting Started with Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229601(v=vs.110).aspx)
or
[The Model-View-Controller(MVC) Pattern with C#/WinForms](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/383153/The-Model-View-Controller-MVC-Pattern-with-Csharp)

Comment: Sir how am I going to display and set the default value 5000 in a textbox in balance form?

Comment: Since now you have a model, which is shared between all forms. You can access it's Balance property. So in your model constructor you can set this.Balance = 5000 then in your balance form you can set textbox.text = this.model.Balance. 

A better practice to use databinding, but if you are not familiar with it, then just stick with what i mentioned before.

Comment: sir an error occurred: Error2 Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'AutomatedTellerMachine.AtmModel' is less accessible than method 'AutomatedTellerMachine.Balance.Balance(AutomatedTellerMachine.AtmModel)'

Comment: you have to make your model public.
public AtmModel model ...

Answer (score 1):

In your withdrawal form add a method like

```
public int GetWithdrawalValue()
{
    int withdrawalValue;
    int.TryParse(textboxWithdrawal.Text, out withdrawalValue);
    return withdrawalValue;
}
```

Show your withdrawal form modal

```
Form3 formWithdrawal = new Form3();
formWithdrawal.ShowDialog();
int valueToWithdraw = formWithdrawal.GetWithdrawalValue();
```

That should do the trick.